# How to create multiple rules for "lapply" function

Tags: r, lapply

Currently, I have an array of list(groupA) like the following example:

```
$AAAAAA
       time  timegap
1  06:00:00        0
2  07:00:00       60
3  08:00:00       40
4  09:00:00        0
5  10:00:00       30

$BBBBBBB
       time  timegap
1  06:00:00        0
2  07:00:00       60
3  08:00:00       40
4  09:00:00        0
5  10:00:00       30
```

I am trying to create a function that generate a dummy variable if timegap is greater than a certain number. But the challenge is the number for generating dummy variable would be different from others if the time in in the range from 07:00:00 to 09:00:00.

What I did was as following:

```
dummytime<-function(x){
  if(x$time>times("07:00:00") & x$time<times("09:00:00")){
    d<-c(1200) 
  }
  else{
    d<-c(600) 
  }
  dummytime<- as.numeric(x$timegap>=d)
  as.data.frame(dummytime)
}

dumtime<-lapply(groupm2,dummytime)
```

However, I got an error like this:

```
Error in if (as.logical(x$time > times("07:00:00") & x$time < times("09:00:00")))
{ : missing value where TRUE/FALSE needed
```

Any suggestion? Thanks for help in advance.

Comment: It is better to mention the package that has the `times` function

Comment: @akrun, Thanks for the notice. the package which includes times function actually is "chron". It's a package for date and time.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Here is one way. Since you used the `chron` package to convert character to time. I have done that. Then, I created a list. Then, `lpply`.

```
library(chron)

# time to Class 'times' 
df1$time <- chron(times = df1$time)
df2$time <- chron(times = df2$time)

# Create a list
ana <- list(df1 = df1, df2 = df2)

#$df1
#      time timegap
#1 06:00:00       0
#2 07:00:00      60
#3 08:00:00      40
#4 09:00:00       0
#5 10:00:00      30

lapply(ana, function(x){
                x$test <- ifelse(x$time >= "07:00:00" & x$time <= "09:00:00",
                1200, 600)
                x

    })

#$df1
#      time timegap test
#1 06:00:00       0  600
#2 07:00:00      60 1200
#3 08:00:00      40 1200
#4 09:00:00       0 1200
#5 10:00:00      30  600

#$df2
#      time timegap test
#1 06:00:00       0  600
#2 07:00:00      60 1200
#3 08:00:00      40 1200
#4 09:00:00       0 1200
#5 10:00:00      30  600
```

Or

```
lapply(ana, transform,
       test = ifelse(time >= "07:00:00" & time <= "09:00:00", 1200, 600))
```

Comment: thanks,@jazzurro, I got clue from your script. Actuall, I achieved the function I want to create by this:        dummytime<-function(x){
d<-ifelse(x$time>times("07:00:00") &x$time<times("09:00:00"),c(1200),c(600))
  dummytime<- as.numeric(x$timegap>=d)
  as.data.frame(dummytime)
}

Comment: @SmithWang I just revised my answer. I am glad that you found your way.:)